# Remove all instances between repeated items in list, Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, repeat

I need to write a function that takes a list, and removes all items from that list that are between two identical items (and keep one of the identical items).

eg.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 1, 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 1, 'i', 'j']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 1, 'c', '2', 'd', '2', 'e', 'f', 1, 'g', 'h']
list3 = ['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 1, 'd', 2, 'e', 'f', 2, 'g']

print(funct(list1))
print(funct(list2))
print(funct(list3))
```

will result in:

```
['a', 'b', 1, 'i', 'j']
['a', 'b', 1, 'g', 'h']
['a', 1, 'd', 2, 'g']
```

You can assume it will always be the case that any second instance of repetition blocks in the list will be always be completely separate, or completely within another block.

eg.

```
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 2, 'd', 1, 'e']
```

or

```
['a', 1, 'b', 1, 'c', 2, 'd', 2, 'e']
```

but never

```
['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 1, 'd', 2, 'e']
```

I've written a code to do this, but do not like the need of creating a separate list, and appending items to that list, and would rather just remove items from the original list.

This is what I have, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
def funct(list):

    unlooped = []
    appending = True
    list_index = 1

    for item in list:

        if appending:
            unlooped.append(item)

        elif item == looper:
            appending = True

        if item in list[list_index:] and appending:
            appending = False
            looper = item

        list_index += 1

    return unlooped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
def unloop(ls):
    return [x for i,x in enumerate(ls) if not set(ls[:i]).intersection(set(ls[i:]))]
```

explanation: take item `x` at position `i` from `ls` if the intersection of items `[0..i-1]` and `[i..n]` is empty i.e. no element appears both before and after `x`.

it works for the 3 examples you supplied, might need to test it for edge cases

Comment: This worked! It's a little confusing to me because I'm relatively new to python (and coding in general haha), but yeah, thanks so much for the quick response :)

Comment: That was meant to be 'item', I was in the middle of changing variable names to make more sense, and just forgot to switch it over. Although the code I have is being used as a part of a greater homework task, I'm mainly using this to understand a general idea to separate approaches, and not just 'copy pasting' code over. The code submitted will be my own :)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "I've written a code to do this, but do not like the need of creating a separate list, and appending items to that list, and would rather just remove items from the original list." I assumed that to mean deleting items from the original list, so I wrote a solution which deletes entire slices from the list. Using a list comprehension is just another way of creating another list and appending items to it so I wanted to avoid that approach.

```
def unloop(lst):
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            j = lst.index(v, i+1)
            lst[i:j] = []
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return lst
```

I think there are ways to make this algorithm more efficient. I will think on it. Just as a side note, it's good to get into the habit avoiding name clashes with built-in objects. For example, if you have a variable named `list`, you will find it difficult to use the built-in `list` name to convert iterables of other types into lists.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's worked in all cases, and is pretty much the approach I wanted to go for, but just didn't know where to start

Comment: And thanks for the advice about list, I'll make sure to avoid that from here on out

Comment: @AlexPowell I've made the code more efficient by using the second optional argument of index. Now the code no longer computes unnecessary slices which should be a bit more efficient.